# How to merge Parent Element and Child element with " : " (colon) in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

Input Xml:

```
<title>Discourse interaction between <italic>The New York Times</italic> and <italic>China Daily</italic></title> <subtitle>The case of Google&#x0027;s departure</subtitle>
```

Required Output:

`Discourse interaction between The New York Times and China Daily: The case of Google's departure`

My code:

```
String x = xml.Element("title").Value.Trim();
```

Now I am getting :

`Discourse interaction between The New York Times and China Daily:`

Answer (score 0):

`<subtitle>` is not a child element of `<title>`, it is a [sibling element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/find-sibling-nodes).  You can see this by formatting your containing element `xml` with indentation:

```xml
<someOuterElementNotShown>
  <title>Discourse interaction between <italic>The New York Times</italic> and <italic>China Daily</italic></title>
  <subtitle>The case of Google's departure</subtitle>
</someOuterElementNotShown>
```

To get the sibling elements following a given element, use [`ElementsAfterSelf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnode.elementsafterself):

```
var title = xml.Element("title"); // Add some null check here?
var subtitles = string.Concat(title.ElementsAfterSelf().TakeWhile(e => e.Name == "subtitle").Select(e => e.Value)).Trim();

var x = subtitles.Length > 0 ? string.Format("{0}: {1}", title.Value.Trim(), subtitles) : xml.Value.Trim();
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HUoLPT).